# Rails: Mail to multiple recipients without CCing them

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to send out mail individually to multiple recipients, but the way it's setup - all the recipients are being CCd on the mail.

NotificationMailer.rb:

```
def send_weekly_digest(user_id)
    @user = User.find(user_id)
    @admin_email = "admin@gmail.com"

    if @jobs.count > 0
      @recipients = [@user.email, @admin_email]
      mail(to: @recipients, subject: "a nice subject")
    end

  end
```

How can I set this up so recipients are not all CC'd ?

Comment: The `:bcc` (blind-carbon-copy) option seems to be what you are looking for (http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionMailer/Base.html search for bcc)

Comment: my point is, why not put the admin_email as the bcc? (Wikipedia: `BCC: blind carbon copy to tertiary recipients who receive the message. The primary (To) and secondary (Cc) recipients cannot see the tertiary (Bcc) recipients`)

Comment: This sounds good. Except what if I want to send same message to multiple regular users without them knowing each others emails?

Comment: put them also in the bcc. That's how the newsletter system usually work, instead of creating tons of emails, one for each client, the compagnies create only one email newsletter with tons of bcc recipients (Wiki again: `Depending on email software, the tertiary recipients may only see their own email address in BCC, or they may see the email addresses of all primary and secondary recipients.` source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blind_carbon_copy)

Comment: Okay thanks. If you want to add an answer I will accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the BCC option:

Usage:

```
mail(to: @user.email, bcc: @admin_email, subject: "a nice subject")
```

Bcc definition from Wikipedia:

> BCC: blind carbon copy to tertiary recipients who receive the message. **The primary (To) and secondary (Cc) recipients cannot see the tertiary recipients**. Depending on email software, the tertiary recipients may only see their own email address in BCC, or they may see the email addresses of all primary and secondary recipients.

Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blind_carbon_copy